# Wrong output when merging linked lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Currently I have the following function to merge two sorted linked lists of type `mylist`. At the moment, there are some bugs that I have not been able to pinpoint and fix so far. What the function is basically supposed to do is, lets say `A = 1 2 3` and `B = 3 4 5`. Then when I merge both (assuming both lists are sorted), `A` will become `1 2 3 3 4 5` and `B` will become `null`.

At the moment, for example when I try, `A = 1 2 3` and `B = 4 5 6` and merge both, `A` becomes `6` and `B` becomes `4`. I know there are problems with the algorithm but I've not been able to pinpoint and fix yet. I'm new to programming. Any help will be appreciated!

```
void mylist::merge(mylist& b)
{

    if (!this->isSorted() || !b.isSorted())
        cout << "error" << endl;

    Node* ptr1 = b.head;

    Node* prev_a = NULL;
    Node* curr_a = head;
    Node* curr_b = ptr1;

    while (curr_b) {
        if (curr_a && head < ptr1) {
            prev_a=curr_a;
            curr_a = curr_a->next;
        }
        else {
            Node* b_next = curr_b->next;
            curr_b->next = curr_a;

            if (prev_a) prev_a->next = curr_b;
            else head = curr_b; // curr_b is first element in 'a'

            if (curr_a) {
                prev_a = curr_a;
                curr_a = curr_a->next;
            }
            curr_b = b_next; 
        }
    }
    return;

}
```

**EDIT:**

I have made the following changes as mentioned but I still get `A = 6` and `B = 4` after merging `A = 1 2 3` & `B = 4 5 6`.

```
void mylist::merge(mylist& b)
{

    if (!this->isSorted() || !b.isSorted())
        cout << "error" << endl;

    Node* ptr1 = b.head;

    Node* prev_a = NULL;
    Node* curr_a = head;
    Node* curr_b = ptr1;

    while (curr_b) {
        if (curr_a && head->key < ptr1->key) {
            prev_a=curr_a;
            curr_a = curr_a->next;
        }
        else {
            Node* b_next = curr_b->next;
            curr_b->next = curr_a;

            if (prev_a) prev_a->next = curr_b;
            else head = curr_b; // curr_b is first element in 'a'

                prev_a = curr_a;

            curr_b = b_next; 
        }
    return;

}
```

Comment: What is `theOther`, it's at the top of your method but not defined anywhere.

Comment: @JamesJenkinson whoops, I meant b. I've changed it.

Comment: In the first if within the loop a part of your condition is `head < ptr1`. This is comparing addresses instead of the values. You have to dereference the pointers first. Something like `*head < *ptr1`assuming you overloaded the operator for your class `Node`

Comment: that `head < ptr1` seems wrong, since if it's true, neither value will change between iterations so you'll always go all the way to the end of `A` without visiting the `else` block again.

Comment: @genisage I had a feeling something was wrong around there. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: replace `head` with `curr_a`. But you'll still have the issue Rambo brought up, which is that you're comparing the addresses of the nodes, not the values they contain. You'll probably also want to update `prev_a` within the `if` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Sorting problem:**

in your instruction

```
    if (curr_a && head < ptr1) {    // argh !!!
```

you compare two pointers to `Node` (i.e. their addresses) and not the value pointed to.

**2) Extreme case (that applies to your test data):**

If first element of list `b` is greater than any elements of list `a` (supposing that you've corrected problem #1), then you will loop until `curr_a` is null, without ever having set `prev_a`.  You would then insert the elements of b at the head of a (in the reverse order)

**3) First merge in the middle of list a:**

In a normal merge,  you could cycle through list `a` until you have the first element of  list `b` which is smaller than the element of `a`.  `prev_a`is still not set at this moment.  So you'll connect the next-element of current-element of `b` to the current element of `a` (which is ok), but then, as  `prev_a` is NULL, you'll connect the head of `a` to the current element of `b`, thus LOOSING the whole chain of elements in `a` that were before the current one.

**Steps to the solution:**

If it's for an assignment given by your teacher:

```
while (curr_b) {
    if (curr_a && curr_a->key < curr_b->key) { // assuming data is stored in the node and has a comparator defined
        prev_a = curr_a;   // keep track of it (WAS MISSING)
        curr_a = curr_a->next;
    }
    else { 
        Node* b_next = curr_b->next;
        curr_b->next = curr_a;

        if (prev_a) prev_a->next = curr_b;
        else head = curr_b; 

        prev_a = curr_b;  // THE ELEMENT you've inserted is now prev_a
                          // curr_a SHALL not change since the next element of b can also be smaller than it 
        curr_b = b_next; 
    }
 }
```

If it's for real code,  you should really consider standard `<list>` container and its existing [`merge()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/) function ;-)

***EDIT:***  I've just realised that there was another issue and updated also the else part in the loop above.  And I realized I was so focused on the key comparison, that I didn't notcie the wrong pointers were used, so that it didn't succeed in all the test cases !

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. that helps. However, there is no comparater defined. What would be a way to approach this without the 'data'?

Comment: ok ! Then remplace `->data` with `->key`.  As `key` is an `int`  the operator `<` is defined and you don't need anything else for the comparison.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error. It was a typo! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The comparison 'head < ptr1' is meaningless. Those are pointers, not values.

ptr1 seems redundant with curr_b

You seem to start by looking for the tail of A. Why not make that a function in its own right?

Continuing with that divide and conquer approach, I'd make functions that test if a list is empty, pop the head off a list returning what it popped, and a function that appends something to the end. Then your final answer is:

```
mylist::merge(mylist &b) {  
  while (!b.empty())
      push_back(b.pop_front());
}
```